# Answering question with yes or no

Tags: responses

if someone asks me "Hasn't it been decided yet?"  and if it hasn't been decided should I answer with:

> **Yes** (it hasn't been decided yet.)

or

> **No** (it hasn't been decided yet.)

Comment: Negative interrogatives are used to express expectations that something should probably already have been done.

Comment: My advice? Take out the parentheses and say the whole thing. (Either answer would be acceptable with the parenthetical statement included.)

Answer (score 2):

If someone asks "Hasn't it been decided yet?", then "yes" means "yes, it *has* been decided", and "no" means "no, it hasn't been decided yet".

That said, some people prefer to give a multiple-word answer to make it clear (e.g. "it has" or "it hasn't").  Sometimes if you give a single-word answer, people will ask for clarification where the context is unclear.

People sometimes get confused about how a "yes" or "no" will be interpreted.

Even native speakers sometimes get "yes" and "no" mixed up when questions are worded in a certain way, so context, tone of voice and manner play a role in interpretation.  If you ask someone "Do you mind if I sit here?", then logically a "yes" is an objection to your sitting there, but in practice it often means "yes, you can sit there".

Answer (score 1):

When someone asks, "*Hasn't it been decided yet?*", in many interactions what they really mean is, "*Has it been decided yet?*", and they will interpret a *Yes* or *No* response in that context.

This is one of those confusing English questions employing a negation. If the question is framed in the positive, "*Has it been decided yet?*", then *Yes* and *No* answers are quite clear responses, but when the negation is used it can easily lead to confusion. In this case it is usually better to offer a longer answer.

The logical response to, "*Hasn't it been decided yet?*", would be, "*Yes, it has not been decided.*", or, "*No, it has been decided.*"

Comment: "Yes" and "not" shouldn't be in the same sentence. If the answer is "no", it should include "not". We should answer a negative question in English just like answering its positive version. So regardless of the presence of "not" in the question, we should always answer "Yes, I am / I do" or "No, I am not / I do not" (for example).