# Yes/ no in questions

Tags: word-usage

> That restaurant can't be very good.
>
> No, it's always empty.

If the second phrase is an agreement, why is there "no", but not "yes"? 
I'm thinking it's possible to use both, but "yes" seems more correct.

I didn't find enough examples to understand it.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-in-english. Also (on ELU): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281663/a-confusion-about-answer-yes-and-no-to-some-complicated-question

Comment: "Yes you are right, it can't be very good" vs "No it is not good"

Comment: Also related: [Answering questions with Yes or No](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149991).